# 'Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')

Tags: python, linux, ssl, tls1.2, tls1.0

I have a LINUX machine with the OpenNao distro (based on GENTOO). This machine has Python 2.7.3. I do not have root permissions.
You can download an executable image in Virtualbox (OpenNAO OS VirtualBox 2.1.2) from the following link (you will probably have to create an account):

https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/resources/software/language/en-gb?sort_by=weight&sort_order=ASC&page=1

My **problem** is that I am trying to make a call request to an AZURE server that has TLS 1.2, with the following code:

```
import requests
url = "www.example-url.com" # it is not a real url
querystring = {"key":"value",}
headers = {'token': "4bfd740f482d48a3a894445eb6a85a83",'Username': "user",'Password':"password"}
#response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring, timeout=30)
```

and I get the following **error**:

```
    /var/persistent/home/nao/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:339: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  SNIMissingWarning
/var/persistent/home/nao/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "heathrowFI-3.py", line 33, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring, timeout=30)
  File "/var/persistent/home/nao/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/var/persistent/home/nao/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/var/persistent/home/nao/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/var/persistent/home/nao/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/var/persistent/home/nao/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I have tried to make the request on other machines (Windows, Ubuntu) with TLS 1.2 and the result is OK.
To get the TLS version of each machine I used the following command

```
python -c "import json, urllib2; print json.load (urllib2.urlopen ('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check')) ['tls_version']"
```

WINDOWS machine with python 2.7 and TLS 1.2 : The result of the request was OK.

UBUNTU machine with python 2.7 and TLS 1.2 : The result of the request was OK.

I think the error is caused by the TLS 1.0 version of the SSL used by NaoQi. The server to which I make the request is Azure and only supports TLS 1.2.
I have checked its TLS in the browser:

[TLS FROM THE SERVER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYhhN.png)

I have no possibility to update Python (I do not have root permissions).

Please, do you know how I can make the request work to the server? Should I update the TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2 on the NAOQI machine? Do you know how to update it ?.

Any help or suggestion would be welcome.

Thanks in advance, regards.